# IndexedDB database of main window is different from an iframe content's one?

Tags: iframe, indexeddb

I have an IndexedDB database with html documents stored inside as blobs and a webapp using an iframe to visualize these documents.

My problem is : I want to get the store of the database where are the html documents everytime I click on a link inside a html document displayed inside the iframe, but it throw an exception when I try. When I'm not "inside" the iframe(the function is inside an eventListener bind to a hypertext link inside the iframe), it gets it without any problem.

The function used is :

```
function getObjectStore(store_name, mode) {
  var tx = db.transaction(store_name, mode); // mode in this case is 'readonly'
  return tx.objectStore(store_name); // line where the exception is thrown when "inside the iframe"
}
```

where db is my database. The exception thrown is :

> Exception... "A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations." code: "11" nsresult: "0x80660006 (InvalidStateError)"

Because everything's all right with other cases and that I don't see any problem in the steps of getting my store, I wanted to know if I have this problem because I can't reach the database of the main window even if the main page and the page in the iframe are from my local server, or because another reason.

Thank you for your advice !

Comment: the message suggest you use write op in readonly transaction. the code you are showing is not helpful to see the problem. iframe should be ok. use chrome dev tool to debug iframe code.

Comment: What I don't understand is why am I using writing operation when I only request the objectStore ? In the calling function, I only do `var store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readonly');` and it is this line that throws an exception. So I try to understand what the problem is, but maybe it is just blocked due to security risks, as said Kristof Degrave. I expected a exception message more suited for the context.

Comment: I tried a 'readwrite' mode, and it didn't change anything, the message stay the same...

Comment: I found my problem is not related to the iframe specifically. This post isn't useful, my real problem is here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830885/error-when-getting-indexeddb-objectstore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexeddb doesn't run inside an iframe deu security risks.

The exception youbare talking about means you are trying to add, edit or delete data in an object store using a readonly transaction. If you want to  manipulate data use a readwrite transaction.

Comment: I thought it was only in case of using data from other domains... So, for any kind of data, indexedDB will not run inside the iframe ? If I use an object element instead of an iframe, will there still be blocking due to security risks ?

Comment: Due the same origin principle frames and iframes are not aloowed because they can be loaded into other domains. Not all browsers implement this correctly. I believe it is possible using chrome

Answer (score 0):

> Known issue - Third-party databases are not visible.

For example, if you use an **iframe** to embed your page while using IndexedDB, your page's IndexedDB data won't be visible.

See issue #943770:
[Issue 943770: DevTools: Show iframe IndexedDB databases](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=943770)

*Workaround* - one option is to open the iframe page **directly** and observe the indexeddb related to the site - instead of working through the iframe container page.